# Convert PMML - Model (Artificial Neural Network) to Java Code

Tags: java, neural-network, pmml

I have a PMML file of a trained Artificial Neural Network (ANN). I would like to create a Java method which simply takes in the inputs and returns the targeted value.

This seems pretty easy, but I do not know how realize it.

The PMML Version = 3.0

**Update: 24.05.2013**

I tried to use the jpmml Java API.

This is how I have done:

(1) Downloaded via Maven Central Repository ([link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjpmml)) three .Jar files:

- pmml-manager-1.0.2.jar
- pmml-model-1.0.2.jar
- pmml-evaluator-1.0.2.jar

(2) Used eclipse to "configure Build path" and added those three external .Jar's

(3) Import my PMML-File named "text.xml" ( an artificial neural network (ANN)) PMML version="3.0"

(4) Tried to run an example "[TreeModelTraversalExample.java](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jpmml/example/TreeModelTraversalExample.java)" provided by the jpmml-project

Obviously it did not work for some reasons:

- the mentioned example is not for ANN's. **How to rewrite it?**
- my PMML-file is in XML-format. **Is it the right format?**
- I do not know how to handle or to add Java API's. **Should I even add those by "configure build path" in eclipse?**

Obvious fact #2, I have no clue what I do :-)

Thanks again and kindest regards.

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPMML should be able to handle PMML 3.X and newer versions of [NeuralNetwork](http://www.dmg.org/v4-1/NeuralNetwork.html) models without problem. Moreover, it should be able to handle all the normalization and denormalization transformations that may accompany such models.

I could use a clarification that why are you interested in converting PMML models to Java code in the first place. This complicates the whole matter a lot and it doesn't add any value. The JPMML library itself is rather compact and has minimal external dependencies (at the moment of writing this, it only depends on commons-math). There shouldn't be much difference performance-wise. You can reasonably expect to obtain up to 10'000 scorings/sec on a modern desktop computer.

The JPMML codebase has recently moved to GitHub: http://github.com/jpmml/jpmml

Fellow coders in Turn Inc. have forked this codebase and are implementing PMML-to-Java translation (see top-level module "pmml-translation") for selected model types: https://github.com/turn/jpmml

At the moment I recommend you to check out the Openscoring project (uses JPMML internally): http://www.openscoring.org

Then, you could try the following:

1. Deploy your XML file using the HTTP PUT method.
2. Get your model summary information using the HTTP GET method. If the request succeeds (as opposed to failing with an HTTP status 500 error code) then your model is well supported.
3. Execute the model either in single prediction mode or batch prediction mode using the HTTP POST method. Try sending larger batches to see if it meets your performance requirements.
4. Undeploy the model using the HTTP DELETE method.

You can always try contacting project owners for more insight. I'm sure they are nice people.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much. I want to convert the trained .pmml model as I want to include a Java-Method (like "inputs x1-x5 and return Y") in an existing program. The neural network itself was trained in a stand-alone program which only allows to export it as a PMML-model. Actually I do think that the JPMML would work, but I do not know how do get it work. As I said before, I am really a noob regarding this. I already tried to get the "openscoring" run, but I think it will not work (n full admin rights here). I really need a step by step guidance for JPMML. I will ask the project owner.

Comment: Hello again. Finally it works. All I needed was indeed the JPMML bundle .jar file. It really works well with my PMML file. Thank you again. Special thanks to the project owner. Regards, Stefan

Comment: @user1808924 Can you please give me the link or example of java code which reads the PMML and predict the score for scikit-learn MultilayerPerceptron .

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use the Cascading API. There's a library called "Pattern" for Cascading, which translates PMML models into Cascading apps in Java.  https://github.com/Cascading/pattern

Generally those are for Hadoop jobs; however, if you use the "local mode" flow planner in Cascading, it can be built as a JAR file to include with some other Java app.

There is work in progress for ANN models. Check on the developer email list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pattern-user

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you need.  It is an open source library that claims to be able to read and evaluate pmml neural networks.  I have not tried it.

https://code.google.com/p/jpmml/

Comment: Dear Jeff, thank you. I gave it already a try but do not know how to use it properly. I will edit my first post to let you see what I have tried so far.