# R nnet model as an equation for use in other programming languages

Tags: r, java, nnet

I've successfully created the model in RStudio using nnet.
But now I need to code it up in Java.
I presume I could take the weights (wts) and build up the equations necessary for the activation functions, but I hope that someone has already written a function to do this.

How do people typically take their R model and implement them in C, Java, etc?

```
str(mynn) gives:

List of 18
$ n            : num [1:3] 1 2 1
    $ nunits       : int 5
$ nconn        : num [1:6] 0 0 0 2 4 7
    $ conn         : num [1:7] 0 1 0 1 0 2 3
$ nsunits      : num 4
    $ decay        : num 0.02
$ entropy      : logi FALSE
    $ softmax      : logi FALSE
$ censored     : logi FALSE
    $ value        : num 26466497
$ wts          : num [1:7] 6.422 -0.433 -11.771 2.086 -12001.039 ...
    $ convergence  : int 0
```

etc...

Perhaps this has been asked before, but hours of google searches has not revealed the answer.

Thank you for your help.  I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use [PMML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language).  The CRAN package [pmml](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html) supports exporting `nnet` models:

```
library(caret)
library(nnet)
library(pmml)

model <- train(
  Sepal.Length~., iris, 
  method='nnet', trace=FALSE, 
  trControl=trainControl(verboseIter=TRUE))
pmml(model$finalModel)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Zach! The pmml is much more understandable than the str() output and I see there are libraries in Java to consume that format. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687649/convert-pmml-model-artificial-neural-network-to-java-code